# MySql without installer download link?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to download the MySQL no-install version, but I can't find it on their site.
Can anyone help? I tried with [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.1/mysql-noinstall-5.1.56-win32.zip) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the latest one from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (32-bit or 64-bit no-install zipped versions are underneath the MSI installer link).

You can also get archived versions if you click "Looking for previous GA versions?" seeing as your question references the very old 5.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

The process for installing MySQL (*noinstall*) from a Zip archive is as follows:

- Extract the archive to the desired install directory
- Create an option file
- Choose a MySQL server type
- Start the MySQL server
- Secure the default user accounts

[Detailed info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-install-archive.html)

[How to use MYSQL no-install on Windows](http://advancedbms-mysql.blogspot.it/2012/07/how-to-use-mysql-no-install-on-windows.html)